# What are unit testing tools for C++ 64-bit applications?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, unit-testing

Can anybody suggest me any unit testing tool used for C++ code for 64-bit applications?
OS: Windows 7
Compiler: Visual Studio 2010
Type: 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I think [GoogleTest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) fully support 64-bit builds. Refer to [this link](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_generate_64-bit_binaries_on_Windows_%28using_Visual_Studi) of the FAQ for how to build the proper version.

Answer (score 0):

Any portable library will work for 64-bit (32-bits doesn't mean the same thing to all operating systems and 64-bit even less so).

Well known unit test libraries for C++ are [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/), [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/) (lightweight) or [CppUnit](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/cppunit/).

Comment: I use CppUnit for 64-bit builds in VS2010 with no problems

Comment: I searched for CPPUnit documentation but I found no documentation which says that it can run 64-bit C++ applications..

Comment: @RuheeJaiswal: Nobody mentions their library can run 64-bit because it's obvious. It would have been big shame if it didn't work and promptly fixed; Win64 is available at least 4 years and Linux distributions have compiled *all* software 64-bit some years before that already.

Comment: @RuheeJaiswal: (you may have to compile it, but I wouldn't even consider not doing it – on Windows that is; I wouldn't compile it on Linux, but Windows is pain with all the static/dynamic debug/release runtime options, so it's easier to just build your support libraries with the compiler settings you need)